# How to use ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, component, 3rd-party-library

We have 4 types of components in Magento 2, as I have been using three of them, but my question is how to use `const LIBRARY = 'library';` component.

As name implies, this is something to include third party libraries, but any one can give me an example on how to include a library and use the lib in global application level.

```
/**#@+
* Different types of components
*/
const MODULE = 'module';
const LIBRARY = 'library';
const THEME = 'theme';
const LANGUAGE = 'language';
```

I did not find any information about `const LIBRARY = 'library';` in the official Magento 2 documentation [Register your component](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/component-registration.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's not documented on the official documentation but here's how it should be done from what I understand:

So it's very similar to the way your register modules, you just need to create `lib/internal/Your/Library/registration.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY,
    'your/library',
    __DIR__
);
```

Also you can find the right location is properly documented here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_conventions.html

To use/load these libraries you follow the same way as it's done with the `Magento\Framework` library. So using :

```
use Your\Library\Custom\Class;
```

You can find the core `registration.php` under `lib/internal/Magento/Framework` folder

Comment: Thanks @Raphael, Can please give me an example on how to use/load these libraries added "LIBRARY = 'library" in third-party/custom implementations.

Comment: Am looking forward to have basic example on how to use this in real time.

Comment: @Krishati95Dev see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can refer from core file's where it is been used .Here is the example this may help you , You need to give name which you want to include :-

> ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY, '', **DIR**);

Example :

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY,
    'magento/test',
    __DIR__ );
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get the answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/163418/36759 to work, but only after declaring namespaces inside the classes in the library, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

From Magento 2.2 the described half-documented library approach does not work anymore. Magento encourages developers to add libraries using composer according to:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10985

What works would be adding your own autoloader:
`lib/internal/Your/Library/registration.php`

```
<?php
namespace Your\Library;

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
  $prefix   = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\';
  $base_dir = __DIR__.'/';
  $len = strlen($prefix);

  if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
    return;
  }
  $relative_class = substr($class, $len);
  $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    require $file;
  }
});
```

This works due to `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` which still includes the following directories:

```
$pathList[] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/internal/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/internal/*/*/*/registration.php';
```